# Problemas con firebase

Tags: html, reactjs, firebase

estoy teniendo una serie de problemas con firebase a la hora de registrar y logear usuarios, el primero de esos problemas es que guarda todo lo que el teclado capta, como si estuviese constantemente por cada tecleo que realizo, mandando el formulario a la base de datos, tanto en el login como en el registro del usuario, el archivo de registro es el siguiente:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import '../css/login-register/login.css'
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
import '../css/login-register/login.css'
import firebase from "../firebase";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'

const Register = (e) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

const auth = getAuth()
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      console.log('Logeado')
      const user = userCredential.user
      // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code
      const errorMessage = error.message
      console.log('error: ' + errorMessage)
    })

  
    return (
      <div>
        <h4 className="center-align">Register</h4>
        <div class="row">
          <form class="col s12 register-form">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate" />
                <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate" />
                <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input onChange={(e) => {
                    setPassword(e.target.value)
                  }}id="password" type="password" class="validate" />
                <label for="password">Password</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setEmail(e.target.value)
                  }}
                  id="email"
                  type="email"
                  class="validate"
                />
                <label for="email">Email</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span>Accept the terms and conditions</span>
            </label>
            <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn col s12">
              Register
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

export default Register
```

No se porque pasa esto, agradezco toda ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes un componente controlado, es decir ambos input `email` y `password` reaccionan a cada keystroke modificando el estado y devolviendo el componente nuevamente; ahora no se ve el método `submit` del `form`, se supone que el botón `Register` debería ser de tipo `submit`. ¿En que momento se hace el submit del `form`? saludos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Mi formulario de registro capta todo lo q escribo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/487425/mi-formulario-de-registro-capta-todo-lo-q-escribo)