# Mi formulario de registro capta todo lo q escribo

Tags: reactjs, firebase

hago este post porque se me presento un problema al hacer un formulario de registro utiliznado React Hooks + Firebase,

El problema consiste en que segun cualquier cosa que toque, este automaticamente se envia a la base de datos,

Aca el formulario de registro:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import '../css/login-register/login.css'
import firebase from "../firebase";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'


const Register = (e) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

const miSubmit = () => {

  const auth = getAuth()
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    console.log('Registrado')
    const user = userCredential.user
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code
    const errorMessage = error.message
    console.log('error: ' + errorMessage + 'Error code  ' + errorCode)
    
  })

  e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Ejecutando submit sin evento');
}

  
    return (
      <div>
        <form action=""  onSubmit={miSubmit}>

        <input type="text" 
        id="email" 
        placeholder="Email"
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>

        <input type="password" 
        placeholder="Password" 
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
        <input className="waves-effect waves-light btn" type='submit' name="Register" value='registro' />
            </form>
      </div>
    )
  }

export default Register
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### múltiples problemas.

1. uno que tu `onSubmit` hace referencia al mismo componente `Register` el cual no debe ser así.
2. Colocas el código de `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` directamente dentro del componente, lo cual ocaciona que se ejecute siempre al usar `setEmail` o `setPassword`.
3. Tu método `onSubmit` nunca se ejecutará si los `input` no están dentro de tu `form`, sobre todo tu `input` de tipo `submit`

Para ver a simple vista el problema ocasionado por `setEmail` o `setPassword` coloquemos un `console.log()` dentro del componente para ver como se imprime y ejecuta cada ves que escribimos en los `input`

Esto unicamente a modo de ejemplo y mostrar lo que sucede cada ves que escribes y el por que de tu problema

```
const Register = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    console.log('Ejecutando todo código dentro de form----');
    ...
```

---

## Solución al problema

### Problema 1 y 2

Para solucionar tu problema, debemos crear un método que se ejecutara unicamente cuando sea el submit y colocarlo en el `onSubmit`

```
const Register = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    console.log('Ejecutando todo código dentro de form----');

    const miSubmit = () => {
        const auth = getAuth()
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                console.log('Logeado')
                const user = userCredential.user
                // ...
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                const errorCode = error.code
                const errorMessage = error.message
                console.log('error: ' + errorMessage)
            })
    }

return (
        <div className="input-field col s6">
            <form action="" onSubmit={miSubmit}>
       //....
```

### Problema 3

Tu `form` debe contener los `input` que controlara o necesitara, incluyendo el `submit`.

```
return (
        <div className="input-field col s6">
            <form action="" onSubmit={miSubmit}>
                <input type="text"
                    className="validate"
                    id="email"
                    value={email}
                    placeholder="Email"
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />

                <input placeholder="Password"
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                <input className="waves-effect waves-light btn" type='submit' name="Register" value='registro' />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
```

---

**Tu código en general debe quedar algo como esto.**

```
const Register = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    console.log('Ejecutando todo código dentro de form----');

    const miSubmit = () => {
        const auth = getAuth()
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                console.log('Logeado')
                const user = userCredential.user
                // ...
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                const errorCode = error.code
                const errorMessage = error.message
                console.log('error: ' + errorMessage)
            })
    }


    return (
        <div className="input-field col s6">
            <form action="" onSubmit={miSubmit}>
                <input type="text"
                    className="validate"
                    id="email"
                    value={email}
                    placeholder="Email"
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />

                <input placeholder="Password"
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                <input className="waves-effect waves-light btn" type='submit' name="Register" value='registro' />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Evitar recarga de pagina al usar `submit`**

para esto unicamente recibimos el evento y utilizamos `e.preventDefault()`

**ejemplo**

```
const miSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Ejecutando submit sin evento');
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Richard, funciono a la perfeccion, te queria hacer una ultima consulta, y es que al darle click a registrar, esto hace que la pagina se actualice y no alcance a ver el console.log que me deberia decir si hay algun problema o no, hay alguna forma de hacer que esto no suceda? Muchas gracias

Comment: @HatoriHanso Actualice mi respuesta y agregue un ejemplo para usar `e.preventDefault()` al final de la respuesta, que te ayudara con lo que quieres

Comment: Hola Richard, no me funciona, la pagina se sigue refrescando cuando le doy click al boton

Comment: @HatoriHanso revisaste que este bien aplicado ? tal cual como en el ejemplo? recuerda que tu submit del form debe estar de la siguiente forma `onSubmit={miSubmit}`

Comment: @HatoriHanso Revisa que este bien escrito `e.preventDefault()` las mayúsculas y minúsculas. también recuerda que `e` debe recibirse como parámetro en tu función `const miSubmit = (e) => {}` . Una ves ayas revisado todo eso, informa si te funciona o no.

Comment: Mira, actualizo el post y te muestro como lo deje

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130098/discussion-between-richard-and-hatori-hanso).

Comment: @HatoriHanso Tu problema sigue siendo que no estas recibiendo `e` en tu método `miSubmit` debe estar tal cual lo muestro en el ejemplo de mi respuesta y como te lo indique en mi comentario anterior.  tu lo definiste en el componente lo cual esta mal, sigue el ejemplo tal cual del arespuesta

Comment: Gracias Richard, disculpa, no me di cuenta no se porque

Comment: @HatoriHanso Preferentemente `e.preventDefault()` debe estar al inicio del método y no al final, pero siempre que funcione no hay problema donde, solo debe estar dentro del método, saludos.